# Count paired instances where their elements are in different columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, countif

My searches for answers have been limited by my lack of knowledge of the appropriate terminology. My goal is to count the number of times a specific `username` appears in one column AND the number `1` appears in another column for that user. I attempted to use COUNTIF, but it doesn't seem to format for that purpose.

What I'm needing is to count the number of instances "username" appears in column K when "1" appears in column Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have =COUNTIFS (you don't mention which version of Excel) please try, in Row1 and copied down to suit:

```
=COUNTIFS(Q:Q,1,K:K,K1)
```

there may be better ways (eg a PivotTable, an array formula or =SUMPRODUCT) but this could be one of the simplest.

Alternatively of course just filter and read the count in the bottom left-hand corner of your screen.

Showing COUNTIFS, SUMPRODUCT, PivotTable and filter options:

[image: SO20749406 example]

In this special case, because one of your criteria is `1`, you might also use SUMIFS.

Because the data happens to start with a list of unique `Users` in order the COUNTIFS version in Row2 (adjusted to `K2` from `K1`) entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and copied down to Row 6 will show a result similar to that in the PT.